# Writing two files togethers to a zipped folder in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames which exist in the R environment. My requirement is that i need to export these two data frames in local directory but both the files should together be present in one zipped folder with some name be it "ECT_MX.gz".

If anyone has tried, then would like to know their approach. Currently i have the solution for reading files from local directory and writing to same directory in zipped folder together. Here is the code for it.

```
filestozip <- dir()
zip(zipfile = "ECT_MX.gz",files = filestozip)
```

This code currently list the files from current directory and writes them to one zipped folder in the same directory.

How can i export two data frames together from R environment to one zipped folder in current directory??

Comment: How about 'write.table' then specify the directory to your desired folder, then you can use your code above.

Comment: Clarity: `.gz` is not "combined/zipped", it is simply "single-file compressed". The accepted filename extension for a product of the `zip(...)` function (and command-line `zip.exe`) is `.zip`; using `.gz` will confuse consumers of your products.